# WordPress Multisite header img src is lost from staging to production

Tags: multisite, custom-header, header-image

I'm working on a Multisite where each site has its own header image. I have a staging and production setup where everything is edited on staging. A new site gets created and it has its own header image, all good.

But when I go to move to production, doing a staging database file export, changing the domain names for production, and then importing that database file to the production server those header images are missing.

In the WP-Admin it sees the `Previously uploaded` image and the src is empty. I get img src="" on inspection of the element.

Anyone else have this experience or something similar? In my `functions.php` I've added custom-header theme support.

```
// Add custom header support
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

This might be where I'm going wrong but I also have this in the `custom-header.php`

```
function my_network_custom_header_setup() {
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'my_network_custom_header_args', array(
    'default-image'          => 'http://mynetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/my-logo-default.png',
    'default-text-color'     => '000000',
    'width'                  => 736,
    'height'                 => 220,
    'flex-height'            => true,
    'wp-head-callback'       => 'my_network_header_style',
 )));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_network_custom_header_setup' );
```

I recently added a default image so at least the page doesn't look broken and that works.

Any suggestions for how debug this issue? Maybe it's my callback that's missing something.

Comment: When you changed your domain in the database, how did you do it? Did you do a basic search replace in a query? Or did you use one of the proper tools? Custom headers aren't saved as URLs, they're attachment IDs

Comment: I've started using `sed` in the Terminal, but that's a a basic search and replace. Thanks @TomJNowell that might give me a place to start!

Comment: @TomJNowell what would be a proper tool?

Comment: PHP serialised data cant be search replaced as the length of the data matters, if it changes the data structure becomes invalid. Use WP CLI to do a search replace instead as it does the necessary handling

Comment: I use the WP Clone plugin to move a site from one place to another. Does all the URL changes needed, etc. Easy to use.